# SQL: Separate different items in a column to make unique columns

Tags: sql, pivot

I am no SQL expert and am a little stuck. I have a database table that looks like :

```
Date        | Equipment | Downtime
------------+-----------+---------
2018-10-03  | PLC       |   0
2018-10-03  | Robo      |   0
2018-10-04  | PLC       | 108
2018-10-04  | Robo      |   0
```

For a system I am making I need to make a chart using this table but I need to separate the equipment column to be different columns like this:

```
Date        | Robo(Time)  | PLC(Time)
------------+-------------+----------
2018-10-03  |  0          | 0
2018-10-04  |  108        | 0
```

So I am storing the data in the third row in a column named after the corresponding contents in the second row. 
Does anyone know how this can be done? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select date, 
       max(case when Equipment = 'PLC' then Downtime end) as PLC,
       max(case when Equipment = 'Robo' then Downtime end) as Robo
from table t
group by date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to join the table on itself over date:

```
select PLC.date,
    Robo.Downtime as [Robo(Time)],
    PLC.Downtime as [PLC(Time)]
FROM table as Robo INNER JOIN table as PLC ON Robo.Date = PLC.Date 
    AND Robo.Equipment = 'Robo' AND PLC.Equipment = 'PLC'
```

Note I fully qualified PLC.date, but you can qualify either.  You just have to pick one because since you are joining itself, it's ambiguous otherwise.